# How does WPF treat a field awaiting a response from Async/Await?

Tags: c#, wpf, asynchronous

I'm trying to clarify my understanding of Async/Await. (I have read much here on SO, but haven't gotten a clear grasp as yet). Lets say I have a window constructor that begins a long process:

```
// Constructor
public MainWindowViewModel() : base()
{
    init();
   ........
}

private async void init()
{
    PatientList = await GetPatientList();   <--- A VERY LONG PROCESS
    .....
}

private ObservableCollection<ViewPatient> PatientList;

private async Task<ObservableCollection<ViewPatient>> GetPatientList()
{
    return new ObservableCollection<ViewPatient>(await MedicalClient.GetAllPatientsAsync());
}
```

So, if I get this right, await will start the `GetPatientList()` method, and then
immediately return to the caller (the `MainWindowViewModel()` which will then complete and display the window.

Now, in the window I have a search button on the names in the list. After a few quick jumps, the finder calls:

```
private async Task<ObservableCollection<ViewPatient>> GetPatientListFromName(string lastname, string firstname, string birthdate)
{
    string birth = string.Empty;
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(birthdate))
    {
        // regex to look for pattern: 00/00/0000, 0/00/0000, 00/0/0000
        Regex regex = new Regex(@"^\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{4}$");
        Match x = regex.Match(birthdate);
        if (!x.Success) return null;
        birth = birthdate;
    }

    string last = lastname ?? string.Empty;
    string first = firstname ?? string.Empty;

   // PatientList = await GetPatientList(); <--Is This Needed?

    var z = PatientList.Where(p =>
       p.Lastname.StartsWith(last.ToUpper()) &&
       p.Firstname.StartsWith(first.ToUpper()) &&
       ((DateTime)p.Birthdate).ToShortDateString().StartsWith(birth));

    return new ObservableCollection<ViewPatient>(z);

}
```

So now my questions are:

1. If the `GetPatientList()` has not completed (so `PatientList` is not known) by the time `GetPatientListFromName(...)` needs it, will `GetPatientListFromName(...)` automatically wait for its completion prior to continuing into the LINQ expression? Or is something more needed?
2. If I include the (commented out) `PatientList = await GetPatientList();` will `GetPatientList()` be started again --even if it is already running?

Comment: NO, `await GetPatientList();` will not release the UI, it's kind a synchronous call.

Comment: 1) What do you mean by "PatientList is not known"? It's null until it isn't. 2) Where did you ever hear that C# methods aren't re-entrant? Of course you can have multiple awaits on it simultaneously. Those two questions go well together, but the answer to both of them is "no, the runtime isn't nearly that clever or mysterious".

Comment: @EdPlunkett Is that to say that if I use PatientList= await GetPatientList() (i.e., remove the comments), it will start it again--even while its still running? How can I correct this code so that it will wait for PatientList to be initialized before continuing on with the linq expression (I don't want to run GetPatientList() again)?  Thanks.

Comment: It sounds like what you want to do may be to avoid calling `GetPatientListFromName()` until the `init()` call to `GetPatientList()` completes. I would also consider not loading the whole patient list on the client at all, but instead a) move the LINQ in `GetPatientListFromName()` to a webservice method that takes the patient name as an argument, or b) expose the patient list as an entity framework EDMX thing (warning: EF is a pain) and do linq to entities on the client.

Comment: What you should do is not allow GetPatientListFromName to be called until PatientList is received, I mean from UI perspective. So show loading indicator and disable all controls which actions require patient list, until it is loaded.

Comment: @EdPlunkett  Sorry to beat a dead horse, but when you say "can have multiple awaits on it simultaneously", does that mean GetPatientList() will be run twice, or when it completes the first time both awaits will complete together? Thanks.

Comment: The two calls have nothing to do with each other. Each starts when you start it and completes when it's done.

Comment: @Rahul To release the UI, do I Need to put it in a Task.Run(...) ?

Comment: NO, if you want to run it in asynchronous mode then don't use `await` keyword. In which case, the UI thread will be free once the call made.

Comment: @Rahul ...but my compiler is unhappy without await?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I'm trying to clarify my understanding of Async/Await.

I suggest that you start off with [my tutorial](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html), which has links to (IMO) the best follow-up resources at the bottom. Since you're writing a WPF app, I would also recommend my article series on async MVVM (particularly the one on [async data binding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn605875.aspx)). SO is great for Q&A, but it's not really meant to be a tutorial/learning site.

The first thing to realize about `await` is how it splits up its `async` method. In particular, this:

```
private async void init()
{
  PatientList = await GetPatientList();
}
```

is essentially the same as this:

```
private async void init()
{
  var task = GetPatientList();
  var result = await task;
  PatientList = result;
}
```

This should make it clear that

1. `GetPatientList` is invoked before the `await` begins.
2. `PatientList` is assigned after the `await` completes.

With that in mind, you can answer your questions:

> If the GetPatientList() has not completed (so PatientList is not known) by the time GetPatientListFromName(...) needs it, will GetPatientListFromName(...) automatically wait for its completion prior to continuing into the linq expression?

No. The `PatientList` will be `null` until the `await` in `init` is completed.

> If I include the (commented out) PatientList = await GetPatientList(); will GetPatientList() be started again --even if it is already running?

Yes. This will invoke `GetPatientList` a second time, creating another task.

---

To solve your *actual* problem (that is, only load `PatientList` once but allow the search button to work appropriately), you can do this a few different ways.

One approach is to *save* an "initialize" task, as such:

```
private Task _initTask;
public MainWindowViewModel() : base()
{
  _initTask = InitAsync();
  ...
}

private async Task InitAsync()
{
  PatientList = await GetPatientList();
  ...
}

private async Task<ObservableCollection<ViewPatient>> GetPatientListFromName(string lastname, string firstname, string birthdate)
{
  ...
  string last = lastname ?? string.Empty;
  string first = firstname ?? string.Empty;

  // Ensure PatientList is loaded.
  await _initTask;

  var z = PatientList.Where...
}
```

This will cause your `Search` button to (asynchronously) wait for `PatientList` if it is not already complete. It's perfectly safe to `await` tasks that are already completed, and also to `await` tasks multiple times.

A nice side benefit of this approach is that the `async void` is transformed to `async Task`. [It's a best practice to avoid `async void`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx).